# Neil Armstrong and Buzz Aldrin alphametic

Tags: no-computers, alphametic

Every letter stands for a digit in decimal representation, 
different letters stand for different digits:

```
      MEN + CAN = REACH - MOON
```

Which digit does each letter represent?
(Please present the full analysis how these digits can be determined.)

Comment: Can we assume that M, C, R don't represent 0?

Comment: Yes: MEN and CAN are three-digit numbers, MOON is a four-digit number, REACH is a five-digit number.

Comment: There is definitely an answer, which I have verified using a script. I won't post it given the `no-computers` tag, but there is certainly an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> 902 + 382 = 10836 - 9552

Solution.

> First there are the "gimme" digits.
>
>  We can rewrite this as `MEN + CAN + MOON = REACH`. A crude upper bound for the right hand side is `9999 + 999 + 999` which is `11997` yielding R = 1. Then we know that E is also either 0 or 1; digit-distinctness forces E = 0. We use this to pin down M as either 8 or 9; 7 is too small as 7999 + 709 + 999 does not clear 10,000. So those are the easy constraints here.
>
>  After that you can condense two pairs of digits together and simplify the problem considerably:
>
>  Writing out what we know, `m0n + can + moon = 10ach`. Reading this modulo ten, we see `3n = h (mod 10).` Since 3 and 10 are coprime, the map `x -> 3x` is a permutation of the digits `0..9` modulo 10. So there is only one degree of freedom here, and we can write `m00 + ca0 + moo0 = 10ac0 + w` where `w = (3*n-h)/10.` More explicitly here is a table:
>
> ```
>      n        =   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
>      h        =   0    3    6    9    2    5    8    1    4    7
>      allowed? =   X    X        m=8        X   m=9   X   m=9  m=8
>  (3*n - h)/10 =             0    0    1         1         2    2
> ```
>
> We can see that `w` is bounded between 0 and 2, and lets us look up a couple pairs of (h, n) numbers. This will be crucial for quickly brute-forcing the rest. When we divide the whole equation by 10 we now have:
>
> ```
>     m0 + moo = 1000 + (ac - ca) - w
> ```
>
> Now comes our second pair that we can condense: we rewrite `ac - ca` as `9 * (a - c)`. Defining `x = a - c` we can see that `x` is bounded between 9-2 = +7 and 2-9 = -7, so **it can be negative**, which is important. We will be using it to take certain guesses for `o` and try to bring them within `0,1,2` for a value of `w`. Our current equation is just:
>
> ```
>     11*o  - 9 * x + w = 1000 - 110 * m.
> ```
>
> Now we are ready to investigate particulars.
>
>  For m=8 we see that `11 * o - 9 * x + w = 120.` Clearly `o > 1` from our distinct-digit constraint, and since `w` is so small we will need negative `x` to fight to bring this 120 down to the appropriate range. Here is a table of the possibilities:
>
> ```
>      o          =     2    3    4   5   6   7   8   9
>      120 - 11*o =    98   87   76  65  54  43  32  21
>      -9*x       =    90   81   72  63  54  36  27  18
>        w        =     8    6    4   2   0   7   5   3
> ```
>
> So we see that when m=8 we have only two possibilities: o=5 and o=6.
>
>  When m=8, o=5 we have `c = a + 7` and `w = 2`. The above table for `w` shows that w=2 only when (n=9, h=7). This leaves no possibilities for c, as `a` is minimum 2 and thus `c` is minimum `9`. Dead end.
>
>  When m=8, o=6 we have `c = a + 6` and `w = 0`, which permits (n=2, h=6), forbidden as o=h, or (n=3, h=9), forbidden because again `a` is minimum 2 and thus `c` is minimum 8, but both 8 and 9 are occupied. Also a dead end.
>
>  So we conclude **m = 9**. Our equation is now `11*o - 9*x + w = 10.` The restriction on `w` is still as onerous as ever:
>
> ```
>  
>      o          =     2    3    4    5    6    7    8
>      10 - 11*o  =   -12  -23  -34  -45  -56  -67  -78
>      -9*x       =   -18  -27  -36  -45  -63  -72  -81
>      w          =     6    4    2    0    7    5    3
> ```
>
> (When o=9 it conflicts with m; also you get a = c + 9 which is similarly impossible.) So we have only two possibilities here:
>  
>  When (o=4, w=2) we have (n=8, h=4), but again o = h, BZZT NO.
>
>  When (o=5, w=0) we have (n=2, h=6), a = c + 5. This is only possible with c = 3, a = 8, because n has 2 and m has 9. DING DING DING.
>
>  This is the above solution and it is unique.

Comment: Could you possibly make this more readable? Put two spaces on the end of a line to enforce a new line.

Comment: @jhabbott with that and some other advice about how to make code blocks in spoiler tags I think I've got it sorted out.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> R=1 E=0 M=9 O=5 A=8 C=3 N=2 H=6

which yields:

> 902 + 382 = 10836 - 9552

Solution:

> Since MOON<9999, MAN<999, CAN<999, REACH <12000, hence R=1. Also from the above, E<2, but E=1 is impossible because R=1 already, hence E=0.

Then

> If M<=7, since MAN<999, CAN<999, MOON<7999, MAN+CAN+MOON < 10,000. Hence M>7. We assume M=9.

Then

> We can simplify the equation given by writing, insteand of CAN, for instance, CAN -> 100C + 10A +N, which allows the following simplification:

Here

> 3N-H = 10 (10 +9(A-C)-11 O)

Hence

> Since the rightmost term, 10 +9 (A-C)- 11 O, is an integer, also (3N-H)/10 must be an integer. It is easy that we can only have X=(3N-H)/10=0,1,2.

Rewriting the above,

> 10 = 11 O - 9(A-C) +X

which can be easily solved by trial and error. It turns out that

> the only solution is O=5, A-C=5, X=0. In order to have X=3N-H=0, we can only have N=2,H=6 because the other possible solution, N=3,H=9 is prohibited by the fact that 9 is already allocated to M.

On the other hand,

> A-C=5 has the unique solution A=8,C=3, given that the other possible solutions, 0,5 - 1,6 - 2-7, 4-9, would all use digits which are allocated.

A similar treatment

> shows that, for M=8, there are no other possible  solutions.